# How to resolve this after successful build of app in android studio

Tags: android, android-debug, android-studio-3.0

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex**

Comment: post your complete error

Comment: what libs do you use. I encountered this when i used the latest leak canary

Answer (score 3):

Step1: Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Step 2: If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

More info please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)