# Android studio build apk failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I get this following error while generating apk or when I am trying to deploy the app to a device, I restarted studio after deleting the .gradle and build folder but it didn't help i has tried the invalidate cache and restart option still i get this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex


:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -
-debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

build gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nrs.nsnik.notes"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 30
    versionName "2.9.3"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    resConfigs "en"
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86_64', 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 3, 'armeabi-v7a': 4, 'arm64-v8a': 5, mips: 
6, 'x86': 7, 'x86_64': 8]
import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    output.versionCodeOverride =
            project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) * 1000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version") {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
//MULTI DEX
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

//CONSTRAINT LAYOUT
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//DESIGN AND SUPPORT LIBRARIES
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'

//FINDBUGS JSR305
implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'

//FIREBASE
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'

//RX JAVA & ANDROID
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.4'

//RX BINDING
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-support-v4:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-design:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:2.0.0'

//CHROME CUSTOM TABS
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'

//TIMBER LOGGER
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'

//GUAVA
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

//DAGGER 2
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

//BUTTER KNIFE
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

//GLIDE
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'

//ROLL BAR
implementation 'com.rollbar:rollbar-android:0.2.1'

//EVENT BUS
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

//AUTO VALUE
compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.1"
annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.1"

//AUTO VALUE PARCEL
annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'

//LEAK CANARY
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

//BLOCK CANARY
implementation 'com.github.markzhai:blockcanary-android:1.5.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am using android studio 3.0 beta - 6.

Comment: Visit here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196274/4853552

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: I already have multi dex enabled and my application class extend MultidexApplication, but still i get the above mentioned build error @ShubhamJain